# Remove Metadata Tags from Videostream with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, metadata

I am trying to remove the language metadata tag from the video stream with ffmpeg and leave everything else untouched.
My code is:

```
ffmpeg -i "input" -metadata:s:v:0 language= -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy "output"
```

The metadata tag is removed afterwards but also other streams, if there are more.

---

Example from a file with more streams:

ID - Stream INPUT

0-video languagetag ger

1-audio languagetag ger

2-audio languagetag eng

3-subtitle languagetag eng

4-subtitle languagetag eng

5-subtitle languagetag ger

6-subtitle languagetag ger

7-chapters

---

ID - Stream OUTPUT

0-video

1-audio languagetag ger

2-subtitle languagetag eng

7-chapters

Does anybody know how to fix this? after some search i can not find any solution.

Thanks for the help.